# SQLite delete with table alias

Tags: sql, sqlite, relational-database

I am trying to alias a table in SQLite, for example by the following command: (it is from the book i am reading"Database Management Systems by Ramakrishnan")

```
DELETE FROM Students S WHERE S.sid=12546
```

This code gives a syntax error. Without aliasing, the following code works:

```
DELETE FROM Students WHERE sid=12546
```

But, if i want to alias the table, what should i do? Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: @bluefeet i solved the delete error there but did not get the answer about aliasing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DELETE` statement operates on a single table and does not use a table alias. so you will have to use your query as :

```
DELETE FROM Students WHERE sid=12546
```

**Update:**
SQLite apparently doesn't support joins with the delete statement, as you can see on the [Syntax diagrams](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#delete-stmt). In short in SQLite, one `DELETE` command deletes from only one table. So aliasing is of no use

Comment: Thanks, but in the book i am reading "Database Management Systems by Ramakrishnan" it is written like this. Do you think it is wrong?

Comment: SQLite apparently doesn't support joins with the delete statement, as you can see on the [Syntax diagrams](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#delete-stmt). So aliasing seems disabled in delete statement

Comment: @bigO Yes, that book is wrong for standard SQL or SQLite. Is it written for another DB like MySQL?

Comment: Maybe it is, i am not sure but yes it is not right for sqlite

Comment: Actually the syntax diagram indicates that it should accept an alias, because it uses [qualified-table-name](https://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#qualified-table-name) and an alias would be useful because `expr` can include sub-queries, e.g: `DELETE FROM foo AS f WHERE EXISTS (SELECT b.id FROM bar AS b WHERE b.key=f.id)`.  This seems like an error in either implementation or syntax documentation.

Comment: Here correct query (example)  without alias : DELETE FROM notification_invoice
WHERE notificationDate >= 1536883200000
  AND providerId in ("1234","5678") 
  AND EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
           FROM notification_invoice t2
          WHERE t2.providerId in ("1234","5678") 
            AND t2.notificationDate = notification_invoice.notificationDate          
            AND t2.ownerKey         = notification_invoice.ownerKey 
            AND t2._id              > notification_invoice._id
    )